# why i am getting error in finding the number of maximum values in a array

Tags: c++, function, max

i wrote function like this
array contains the numbers and function should return the number of maximum values

```
int birthdayCakeCandles(vector<int> ar) {
  long arraySize = sizeof(ar) / sizeof(ar[0]);
  long maxHeight = ar[0];
  long number = 0;
  long i;

  for (i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    if (ar[i] >= maxHeight) {
      maxHeight = ar[i];
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    if (ar[i] == maxHeight) {
      number++;
    }
  }

  return number;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: this question is from hacker rank and some test cases went correct and some wrong ..out of 10 testcases only 3 are corrct,i don't know why this is happening and i am new to programming

Comment: The `sizeof(ar)/sizeof(ar[0])` trick does not work if `ar` is a `std::vector`.   That trick only works for C-style arrays - not for pointers, and not for C++ containers.

Comment: There are many algorithms in the standard library that could help 
you. For example https://cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element

Comment: @IshwarJoshi hackerrank and other sites of that kind are not a good starting point to learn a programing language. And even if you know much of the language it is still doubtful to see them as a learning platform.

Comment: @t.niese I very much agree. Such sites are *not* a good learning platform.

Comment: Please suggest me the platforms for learning

Answer (score 2):

This line of code:

```
long arraySize = sizeof(ar)/sizeof(ar[0]);
```

is not doing what you want. `sizeof` returns the size of the object, not the number of elements in the container.

Instead, you can simply do:

```
auto arraySize = ar.size();
```

since `vector` knows its own size, and you can query that.

---

Also, there are algorithms to do what you want, instead of writing raw loops.

```
auto maxHeight = *std::max_element(ar.begin(), ar.end());
auto number = std::count(ar.begin(), ar.end(), maxHeight);
```

Comment: `ar.size()` returns an unsigned integral type - which is `std::vector<int>::size_type` and that is (often, but not guaranteed by the standard) `std::size_t`.   A `long` cannot (necessarily) represent the value returned.   In C++11 and later, you can also let the compiler work out the correct type, by doing `auto arraySize = ar.size();`.

Comment: @Peter Good point, edited the answer, thanks. (I'm going to assume OP has access to at least c++11).